# why does UFW block ICMP destination-unreachable messages despite apparently having rules to allow them?

Tags: server, iptables, firewall, ufw, ntp

Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, I am running UFW with mostly default configuration, have allowed some ports through with "ufw allow" but haven't done any manual blocking or config files editing.

I was checking UFW logs and noticed that incoming ICMP destination-unreachable messages (both IPv4 and IPv6) are being blocked for unclear reasons.

UFW appears to have default configuration to allow these through:

```
root@hostname:/etc/ufw# grep -R icmp * | grep dest
before.rules:-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
before.rules:-A ufw-before-forward -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
before6.rules:-A ufw6-before-input -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
before6.rules:-A ufw6-before-output -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
before6.rules:-A ufw6-before-forward -p icmpv6 --icmpv6-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
```

Here's what I'm seeing in the logs:

IPV4:

```
Apr 26 07:50:04 hostname kernel: [721900.768277] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=XXX SRC=(foreignIPV4) DST=(myIPV4) LEN=104 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=11553 PROTO=ICMP TYPE=3 CODE=3 [SRC=(myIPV4) DST=(foreignIPV4) LEN=76 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=50 ID=55473 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=123 DPT=30516 LEN=56 ]
```

Note: TYPE=3 CODE=3 = destination unreachable / port unreachable

IPV6:

```
Apr 25 17:58:36 hostname kernel: [672013.171362] [UFW BLOCK] IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=XXX SRC=(foreignIPV6) DST=(myIPV6) LEN=144 TC=40 HOPLIMIT=240 FLOWLBL=0 PROTO=ICMPv6 TYPE=1 CODE=4 [SRC=(myIPV6) DST=(foreignIPV6) LEN=96 TC=32 HOPLIMIT=50 FLOWLBL=950125 PROTO=UDP SPT=123 DPT=48280 LEN=56 ]
```

Note: TYPE=1 CODE=4 = destination unreachable / port unreachable

The ICMP messages are in relation to NTP traffic (UDP port 123); I run an NTP server for ntppool.org and sometimes when my server responds to a client, the client responds back with an ICMP message indicating that the port they sent the initial NTP request from isn't reachable. At this time I'm not too interested in why some of the clients respond back that way, I'm just trying to figure out why UFW is blocking the ICMP messages.

For testing, I found a program called "nping" I could run from my home Windows system to send my server custom ICMP messages.  I tried sending destination unreachable messages to see if they would appear in the UFW log but they did not.  So it's possible that UFW isn't blocking 100% of these messages but is blocking some based on unknown criteria.

Adding "iptables -xvnL" output:

```
root@hostname:/var/log# sudo iptables -xvnL
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 12439 packets, 776590 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
145170103 11118327896 ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
145170103 11118327896 ufw-before-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 3633596 110434934 ufw-after-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 3630280 110246698 ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 3630280 110246698 ufw-reject-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 3630280 110246698 ufw-track-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-before-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-after-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-reject-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ufw-track-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 16 packets, 960 bytes)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
79090294 6301946512 ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
79090294 6301946512 ufw-before-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   15895   983433 ufw-after-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   15895   983433 ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   15895   983433 ufw-reject-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
   15895   983433 ufw-track-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      37     2886 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:137
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:138
      11      548 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:139
     187     9508 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:445
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:67
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:68
       0        0 ufw-skip-to-policy-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     786    47222 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
       0        0 ufw-user-forward  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      34    29905 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 6164343 472366977 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
     845    74528 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
     845    74528 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 3
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 11
       0        0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 12
    9836   782534 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:67 dpt:68
 4502728 342015963 ufw-not-local  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            224.0.0.251          udp dpt:5353
       0        0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            239.255.255.250      udp dpt:1900
 4502702 342013987 ufw-user-input  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
      34    29905 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
 5271469 405354822 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
      62     4258 ufw-user-output  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-logging-allow (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW ALLOW] "

Chain ufw-logging-deny (2 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     620    55772 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate INVALID limit: avg 3/min burst 10
     165    13988 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW BLOCK] "

Chain ufw-not-local (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
 4502728 342015963 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type LOCAL
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type MULTICAST
       0        0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ADDRTYPE match dst-type BROADCAST
       0        0 ufw-logging-deny  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 10
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-input (7 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     235    12942 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-skip-to-policy-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       9      540 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW
      37     2758 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate NEW

Chain ufw-user-forward (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-input (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
     401    23204 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
     329    19016 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:443
 4489126 341176077 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:123
     132     3750 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:37

Chain ufw-user-limit (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 0 level 4 prefix "[UFW LIMIT BLOCK] "
       0        0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable

Chain ufw-user-limit-accept (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
       0        0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain ufw-user-logging-forward (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-input (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-logging-output (0 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain ufw-user-output (1 references)
    pkts      bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Comment: We would have to see your entire iptables rule set to be able to comment. Do `sudo iptables -xvnL`. Even then it might be difficult because UFW generated iptables rule sets are hard to follow and also because UFW uses the same log prefix in multiple rules.

Comment: added the iptables output

Comment: Well, I guess it thinks the packet is INVALID. In your "ufw-before-input" chain try moving your "icmptype 3" rule to before the INVALID check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was related to the fact that I had edited my before.rules and before6.rules to disable connection tracking for NTP traffic.  This apparently causes ICMP messages related to that traffic to be flagged as "invalid" connection tracking state

in the standard configuration, the "invalid" dropping happened before the ICMP allowing:

```
# drop INVALID packets (logs these in loglevel medium and higher)
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP

# ok icmp codes for INPUT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT
```

I edited both the before.rules and the before6.rules to swap these two blocks so that the ICMPs are allowed before the "invalid" check happens:

```
# ok icmp codes for INPUT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type destination-unreachable -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type time-exceeded -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type parameter-problem -j ACCEPT
-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -j ACCEPT

# drop INVALID packets (logs these in loglevel medium and higher)
# moved to after ICMP to prevent NTP stuff from being blocked
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j ufw-logging-deny
-A ufw-before-input -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
```